# Tensorflow 1.12.2 dependency issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I was trying to run command
pip install -r requirements.txt -r requirements-local.txt

But I faced this issue I run python 3.8 and I couldn't understand why I also installed tensorflow too

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.12.2 (from versions: 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.12.2

Answer (score 0):

[Tensorflow version 1.12.2](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/1.12.2/) is not compatible with Python version 3.8. The first version compatible with it is [Tensorflow version 2.2.0](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.2.0/) (You can check the compatibility in the links in the section `Programming Language`).

So, to fix the problem you need to change the `requirements` to install the 2.2.0 at least. Notice that [Tensorflow is already on version 2.9.1](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.9.1/) that is compatible with Python version 3.10.